# Content Security Policy Error on displaying youtube IFRAME through my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

from the api of youtube https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

I made a page for my chrome extension,
this is my frame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is how I am calling it in my content.js

```
 var extensionOrigin = 'chrome-extension://' + chrome.runtime.id;
       if (!location.ancestorOrigins.contains(extensionOrigin)) {
           var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
           // Must be declared at web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
           iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('frame.html');
       
           // Some styles for a fancy sidebar
           iframe.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;top:0;left:0;display:block;' +
                                  'width:300px;height:100%;z-index:1000;';
           document.body.appendChild(iframe);

       }
```

but its giving a security policy error, the error I am getting is that **Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash .... is required to enable inline execution.**

I've tried adding this line in my frame.html

```
**<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />**
```

but didn't work

also tried this code    `"web_accessible_resources": ["frame.html"],  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://*; object-src 'self'",`
in my manifest file but it also not work.

What's the best solution to over come this? Any small help will be appreciated

Comment: why haven't you added `unsafe-inline` in `web_accessible_resources` like the suggestion in the error?

Comment: I added that as well but still the same error